# Multible Timers on One Page

Tags: javascript, html

so I have been trying various solutions and no luck for the whole day, as im not strong in JS :(

This is the main script, and Im able to run it

```
<script>
var cdown;
function startCount()
{
    cdown = setInterval(count, 1000);
}
function count()
{
    var do_wait = Math.ceil(4*Math.random()); 
    if (do_wait == 4) { 
        var rand_no = Math.ceil(3*Math.random()); 
        var el = document.getElementById('counter');
        var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
        var newNumber = currentNumber - rand_no;
        if (newNumber > 0) {
            el.innerHTML = newNumber;
        } else {
            el.innerHTML = "Sold Out"; 
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

IN body i call it like this

```
<body onLoad="startCount();">
```

Everything works fine and in the page I have code for display

```
<span id="counter">181</span>
```

So when I load my body the counter starts to count down, but when I tried adding another counter, like

```
<span id="counter">181</span></span>
<span id="counter">281</span></span>
```

Then only the first one will count down, i tried making a new function for cdown and etc, but I just couldn't get both of them running :/

Comment: Don't use the same `id` more than once on your page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build on the previous answer, you should alter your `count` function to take the id of the element you want to count down. For example

```
function count(elementId)
{
    var do_wait = Math.ceil(4*Math.random()); 
    if (do_wait == 4) { 
        var rand_no = Math.ceil(3*Math.random()); 
        var el = document.getElementById(elementId); // use the function argument here
        var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
        var newNumber = currentNumber - rand_no;
        if (newNumber > 0) {
            el.innerHTML = newNumber;
        } else {
            el.innerHTML = "Sold Out"; 
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can call the function(s) like this:

```
var cdown1,
    cdown2;
function startCount()
{
    cdown1 = setInterval(function() {
        count('counter1'); }, 1000);

    cdown2 = setInterval(function() {
        count('counter2'); }, 1000);
}
```

And your HTML would look like this:

```
<span id="counter1">181</span>
<span id="counter2">281</span>
```

Comment: Hi, if you're taking this approach you would be better passing in an array of elementIds and iterating over them when needed. Otherwise you're performing math twice when it isn't needed. Of course it depends on your application, but from the question it sounds like both timers need to reflect the same value.

Comment: The math is happening on every interval iteration anyway. And it looks like the OP might want the timers random-ness to be different for each timer.

Comment: Yes, so the more timers you have the more math you have being performed which isn't realistically a great approach unless the timers are intended to have different values. Of course, this is depending on the application. Not bad mouthing your implementation, as I would do something similar as it's more flexible than my answer. Just writing this so people using this implementation will know to not perform the math each time if they want to use the true identical value on each timer.

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm, i really need to learn more JS :/ spent a day without figuring it out

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare different `id` for each of your spans and call functions on them to start the countdown directly on each. Hope this helps.

```
<span id="counter1">181</span></span>
<span id="counter2">281</span></span>
```

and

```
function count()
{
  var do_wait = Math.ceil(4*Math.random()); 
  if (do_wait == 4) { 
    var rand_no = Math.ceil(3*Math.random()); 
    var el1 = document.getElementById('counter1');
    var el2 = document.getElementById('counter2');
    var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
    var newNumber = currentNumber - rand_no;
    if (newNumber > 0) {
      el1.innerHTML = newNumber;
      el2.innerHTML = newNumber;
    } else {
      el1.innerHTML = "Sold Out";
      el2.innerHTML = "Sold Out"; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Both answers are correct, but the second one was more what I was looking for :)

Comment: @user3146987 Glad you got it sorted. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Something more independent?

http://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/oXZxXY

```
var counter = function(id){
  var element = document.getElementById(id),
      interval = false,
      counter = 0;

  var start = function(){
    if (!interval) {
      interval = setInterval(count, 1000);
    }
  }

  var stop = function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = false;
  }

  var count = function(){
      counter ++;
      element.innerHTML = counter;
  }


  return {
    start : start,
  };
}
window.onload = function(){
  var myCounter = counter('counter');
  myCounter.start();

  var myCounter2 = counter('counter2');
  myCounter2.start();
}
```

You can add the logic about ramdom.

The problem was that you only can use a unique id, and as well you are sharing variables in a global scope.